# Django Managment_form

Tags: python, html, django

I need to create a comment form on my site. When I try to display `comment_form` in HTML instead of the browser, I receive this error:

```
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'].
```

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Here is models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(self.category_name)


class Category_Form(forms.Form):
    category_name = forms.CharField(label='Category_name', max_length=255)

class Comments(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    article = models.ForeignKey('Article')

class Comments_Form(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(label='Comment', max_length=512)
    article_id = forms.CharField()
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    short_text = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    full_text = models.CharField(max_length=5024)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')


class Article_Form(forms.Form):
    author = forms.CharField(label='author_article', max_length=100)
    title = forms.CharField(label='title_article', max_length=255)
    short_text = forms.CharField(label='short_text_article', max_length=1024, widget=CKEditorWidget())
    full_text = forms.CharField(label='full_text_article', max_length=5024, widget=CKEditorWidget())
    date = forms.DateTimeField()
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.order_by('category_name'))
```

My views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.template import RequestContext
from sghome.models import News_Form, News, Article_Form, Article, Category, Category_Form, User, User_Form, \
    Comments_Form, Comments
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def Show_Article_Site(request, num):
    article = list(Article.objects.filter(id=num))
    CommentFormSet = formset_factory(Comments_Form)
    formset = CommentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
    # formset = CommentFormSet()
    return render_to_response('Show_Article_Site.html', {'article': article, 'formset': formset, },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
def Create_Comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # formset = CommentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        Comment = Comments()
        Comment.comment = request.POST['form-0-comment']
    else:
        Show_Article_Site.formset = Show_Article_Site.CommentFormSet()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(Show_Article_Site))
```

And my template:

```
{% extends "base_site.html" %}

{% block center_site %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="create_news">
        {% for artic in article %}
            <br><p>Автор: </p> {{ artic.author }}
            <br><p>Дата: </p> {{ artic.date }}
            <br><p>Заголовок: </p>{{ artic.title }}
            <br><p>Текст: </p>{{ artic.full_text }}
        {% endfor %}
        <form method="post" action="/Create_Comment/">

            {% for form in formset %}
                {{ form.comment }}
                <input type="submit" value="Add">
            {% endfor%}

        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
formset = CommentFormSet()
```

Instead of

```
formset = CommentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Cause your request.POST and request.FILES are not initiated in that place